# RSpec Mock - class does not implement the instance method: jql. Perhaps you meant to use `class_double` instead?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to mock method which use [Jira-Ruby gem with jql lib](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/blob/master/lib/jira/resource/issue.rb#L67)

```
def call
  client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
  client.Issue.jql(
    "project = #{project_key} AND
    status != Done AND
    status != Closed AND
    status != Cancelled AND
    status != Followup",
    query_options
  )
end
```

my mock:

```
  let(:jql_options) do
    [
      "project = TSW-123 AND
      status != Done AND
      status != Closed AND
      status != Cancelled AND
      status != Followup",
      query_options
    ]
  end
  let(:query_options) do
    {
      start_at: 0,
      max_results: 1000
    }
  end
  let(:jira_client) { instance_double(JIRA::Client) }
  let(:issue) { instance_double(JIRA::Resource::Issue) }
  let(:issue_factory) { instance_double(JIRA::Resource::Issue) }

  before do
    allow(JIRA::Client).to receive(:new).with(options).and_return(jira_client)
    allow(jira_client).to receive(:Issue).and_return(issue_factory)
    allow(issue_factory).to receive(:jql).with(*jql_options).and_return(issue)
  end

  it 'connect to the project' do
    expect(subject.call).to eq(project)
  end
```

I'm getting an error:

> JIRA::Resource::Issue class does not implement the instance method: jql. Perhaps you meant to use `class_double` instead?

Comment: as the error says, `jql` method is an class method (defined as `self.jql) so, it should work if you change `instance_double` to `class_double` in `issue_factory` definition. Also, i think you can just say `allow(JIRA::Resource::Issue). to receive...`

Comment: "Also, i think you can" I'm prettu sure that's required, otherwise the mock will be just this local `issue_factory`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You're using mocking syntax for static values, not objects. My answer to your other question here should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60404227/4024628
  IMO, the use of instance_double here is fine because you are mocking instances, though if you are going to call the mocked object's methods you often need to define their responses in the instance_double declaration (as mentioned in my linked comment).
- Be careful with testing mocked behavior; you should only need to test that the client object is created with certain options, and that `jql` is called with specific args (meaning, make sure you're validating your code's behavior against breaking changes -- not the gem's behavior).
- Your spec is testing that `call` returns `project`, but you haven't defined or mocked that anywhere?
- You are also defining `issue_factory` and `issue` as instance_doubles of the same class, which is inconsistent with the documentation for the classes you're using (typo?).

Something like this might be sufficient:

```rb
# You should always name your subject if you are calling methods on it
subject(:instance) { described_class.new }

let(:client)        { instance_double(JIRA::Client)
let(:issue_factory) { instance_double(JIRA::Resource::IssueFactory) }
# This likely needs to be an OpenStruct instead since docu says it returns an obj
let(:project)       { instance_double(JIRA::Resource::Project) }

before do 
  allow(client).to receive(:new).with(options)  { client }
  allow(client).to receive(:Issue) { issue_factory }
  allow(issue_factory).to receive(:jql).with(*jql_options) { project }
end

it 'creates client with correct options' do 
  expect(client).to receive(:new).with(options) 
  instance.call
end

it 'calls #jql with correct options' do
  expect(issue_factory).to receive(:jql).with(*jql_options)
  instance.call
end

it { expect(instance.call).to eq(project) }
```