# RSpec mock method inside of select loop

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I want to test simple class which iterate through array of hashes and return only those with status Pending which were updated more than 2 days ago.

```
  class FetchPending
    PROJECT_KEY = 'TPFJT'
    TWO_DAYS = Time.now - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60

    def call
      project.select do |issue|
        issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') == 'Pending' &&
          DateTime.parse(issue.fields.dig('updated')) < TWO_DAYS
      end
    end

    private

    def project
      @project ||= Jira::ProjectConnection.new(PROJECT_KEY).call
    end
  end
```

How to test `fields` method which is a method of [Jira-Ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby). I think it [comes from here (Field class in resource of gem)](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/blob/master/lib/jira/resource/field.rb) because nowhere else have I found `fields` method.

Here are my thoughts after debugging:

- `project.class` - Array
- `issue.class` - JIRA::Resource::Issue

my natural thinking was:

```
  before do
    # (...) some other mocks
    allow(JIRA::Resource::Issue).to receive(:fields)
  end
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Failure/Error: allow(JIRA::Resource::Issue).to receive(:fields)
>
> JIRA::Resource::Issue does not implement: fields

I have been struggling with this problem for DAYS, I'm pretty desperate here. How to mock this method?

Here is my rest of my specs:

```
RSpec.describe FetchPending do
  subject { described_class.new }

  let(:project_hash) do
    [
      {
        'key': 'TP-47',
        'fields': {
          'status': {
            'name': 'Pending'
          },
          'assignee': {
            'name': 'michael.kelso',
            'emailAddress': 'michael.kelso@example.com'
          },
          'updated': '2020-02-19T13:20:50.539+0100'
        }
      }
    ]
  end
  let(:project) { instance_double(Jira::ProjectConnection) }

  before do
    allow(Jira::ProjectConnection).to receive(:new).with(described_class::PROJECT_KEY).and_return(project)
    allow(project).to receive(:call).and_return(project_hash)
    allow(JIRA::Resource::Issue).to receive(:fields)
  end

  it 'return project hash' do
    expect(subject.call).include(key[:'TP-47'])
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to `allow` on the class itself and not an instance of the class? I think you're declaring that `JIRA::Resource::Issue.fields` is now defined, but not on any given instance.

Comment: Also is it `JIRA` or `Jira`? You've used both styles in here, but Ruby is case-sensitive.

Comment: Another thing to consider is using something like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to get reliable playback of API calls. This often works better than trying to mock and stub an existing implementation.

Comment: So `allow(JIRA::Resource::Issue).to receive(:new).and_return(issue)` where issue is instance double of `JIRA::Resource...` and in new line of before `allow(issue).to receive(:fields).and_return(project_hash)` - I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `Jira` is my module `JIRA` is module from gem. I know I could use VCR but to be honest I don't know how to implement it to my app.

Comment: Having two modules with basically the same name, but not, is really confusing, but okay. VCR is really simple in practice, so I'd experiment with it and see if it solves your problem before you go back to hammering on this particular approach. I've seen VCR solve a lot of complex problems by just stubbing out HTTP calls instead of lots and lots of internals.

Comment: Rather than stub `project` to be a plain hash, can you try and make the stubbed value be something more accurate, e.g. a list of `Jira::ProjectConnection` instances which have custom values set? Sometimes you have to dig a little into the gem's source code to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @maxpleaner "a list of Jira::ProjectConnection instances" ? what do you mean?

Comment: @tadman damn, I was trying to setup this VCR but with no results, I even burn 19$ for Gorails but like everywhere, they only show some stupid example which are not related with real life project.

Comment: That's not great, then. Was worth a shot!

Comment: @mr_muscle sorry, that wasn't really accurate. What I meant was to check what the actual return value of `Jira::ProjectConnection.new(PROJECT_KEY).call` is (it's probably not a hash) and have your test provide something of the same type as the stubbed return value

Comment: In debugging mode if I check `Jira::ProjectConnection.new(PROJECT_KEY).call.class` it will be an `Array`

Comment: @mr_muscle yes, an array composed of what? And can you re-build such objects from your test?

Comment: @maxpleaner it's an array composed of `JIRA::Resource::Issue`. Unfortunately I gave up - I've learned how to use VCR and it solved all of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[and_return](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-a-return-value) is generally used for returning a value (such as a string or an integer) or sequence of values, but for objects you sometimes need use a [block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation). Additionally, if `call` is a valid method on a `Jira::ProjectConnection` object that returns the value of project_hash, you can directly mock its behavior when declaring your instance double (this functionality is unclear from the Relish docs bc they are kinda terrible). Something like this will probably work:

```rb
let(:project) { instance_double(Jira::ProjectConnection, call: project_hash) }

before do
  # Ensure new proj conns always return mocked 'project' obj
  allow(Jira::ProjectConnection).to receive(:new).with(
    described_class::PROJECT_KEY
  ) { project }
end
```

If it still doesn't work, try temporarily replacing `described_class::PROJECT_KEY` with `anything` to debug; this can help you confirm if you specified the wrong arg(s) being sent to `new`.

With regard to the error message, it looks like JIRA::Resource::Issue [doesn't have a `fields` attribute/method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/JIRA/Resource/Issue), though [`fields` appears to be nested in `attrs`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/JIRA/Base#attrs-instance_method)? The [`JIRA::Resource::Project#issues` method also translates the issues in the JSON into Issue objects](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/JIRA/Resource/Project), so if you're using that method you will need to change the contents of `project_hash`.